# Смена изображений

Tags: html, javascript

Собственно, вопрос вот в чем, есть такая шапка:
http://raweinteractive.com/test/

И как можно реализовать плавную смену изображения? Мышкой ведешь в одну сторону - меняется фон, изображения и т.д., ведешь в обратную сторону мышь - и все обратно. В общем, не так убого, как это на данный момент сделано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.rausch.ru/ - посмотрите, как тут реализовано. Думаю, вам это подойдет. )

Реализовано через Tween Max (http://greensock.com/tweenmax).